# Random number not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code that looks at an xml file and attempts to randomly select a value but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. It keeps selecting the same item, only after refreshing the page over 100 times does the number update - anyone see a problem with the below code?

```
static Random random = new Random();

private void GenerateRandomCode()
{
    string path = base.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\App_Data\captchaconfig.xml";

    try
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(path));
        XmlNodeList list = document.SelectNodes("/codes/code");
        XmlNode node = list[random.Next(0, list.Count - 1)];
        txtHidden.Value = node.Attributes["id"].Value;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHidden.Value))
    {
        GenerateRandomCode();
    }


    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do something, nothing to do with GenerateRandomCode()
    }
}
```

I have created a new instance of `Random()` outside of this method, in this example I've called it `random`.

### UPDATE

OK I've made some updates to the code sample above to try answering a few of your questions. I've also made `random` which still has the same result.

An example of the XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<codes>
  <code id="0">570582</code>
  <code id="1">307157</code>
  <code id="2">588869</code>
  <code id="3">994165</code>
  <code id="4">126340</code>
  <code id="5">324903</code>
  <code id="6">644656</code>
  <code id="7">537704</code>
  <code id="8">344852</code>
  <code id="9">730435</code>
  .
  .
  .
  <code id="299">711202</code>
</codes>
```

Comment: Add the code for creating the random object

Comment: Can you show us the code where you instantiate the random instance?

Comment: Can you show us where you call GenerateRandomCode? Is the view state already loaded or not?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint server side and in the immediate window in visual studio call the function several times, do you still get the same result? Are you maybe caching the returned page?

Comment: is random static? Otherwise try making it static. Regardless of c# supporting global or not

Comment: What happens, when you remove everything else from that method and just have `txtHidden.Value = random.Next().ToString();`? And if that value doesn't change, how about `txtHidden.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff");`?

Comment: For the record: the last item will never be selected: maxValue
The *exclusive* upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

Comment: You only call `GenerateRandomCode()` if `txtHidden.Value` is null or empty. Are you sure it is after the first time?

Comment: Corak, `txtHidden.Value = random.Next().ToString();` gives me `1295814419` and `txtHidden.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff");` gives me `20141110150623177567`, refreshing the page doesn't update the result. And yes, I am only calling `GenerateRandomCode()` if `txtHiddenField` is null or empty.

Comment: First make sure you are holding CTRL or SHIFT ( depends on browser ) when refreshing the page to avoid loading from cache and see if you have the same problem.  You may need to put a no cache header.

Comment: @IbrarHussain - So now we established, that the method itself is fine. No matter what you do there, the value of `txtHidden` doesn't change on refresh. That leaves the two other possibilities (which were already mentioned): either a cached version of the page is displayed, or `GenerateRandomCode()` is only called once. Can you check, how many times `GenerateRandomCode()` is called?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try manually seeding your Random: var random = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 0));

Comment: @WhoIsRich - how would that help? `new Random()` will call `new Random(Environment.TickCount)`.

Comment: If you put a brake point in if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHidden.Value)) it will be clear what the problem is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64640/discussion-on-question-by-ibrar-hussain-random-number-not-upating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody's help with this, the problem was that the page was being cached. I had a look at the physical page on the web server and noticed this at the top:

```
<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="Full" %>
```

Removing this fixed the problem.